# Best approach for collision detection with HTML5 and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I'm trying to make a little platform game with pure HTML5 and JavaScript. No frameworks.

So in order to make my character jump on top of enemies and floors/walls etc., it needs some proper collision detection algorithms.

Since I'm not usually into doing this. I really have no clue on how to approach the problem.

Should I do a re-check in every frame (it runs in 30 FPS) for all obstacles in the Canvas and see if it collides with my player, or is there a better and faster way to do so?

I even thought of making dynamic maps. So the width, height, x- and y coordinates of the obstacle are stored in an object. Would that make it faster to check if it's colliding with the player?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Should I re-check in every frame (it runs on 30 FPS)?

Who says it runs in 30 FPS? I found no such thing in the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element). Closest you'll get to have anything to say about the framerate at all is to programmatically call [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) or the newish, more preferred, [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) function.

However, back to the story. You should always look for collisions as much as you can. Usually, writing games on other platforms where one have a greater ability to measure CPU load, this could be one of those things you might find favorable to scale back some if the CPU has a hard time to follow suit. In JavaScript though, you're out of luck trying to implement advanced solutions like this one.

I don't think there's a shortcut here. The computer has no way of knowing what collided, how, when- and where, if you don't make that computation yourself. And yes, this is usually, if not at all times even, done just before each new frame is painted.

### 2. A dynamic map?

If by "map" you mean an array-like object or multidimensional array that maps coordinates to objects, then the short answer has to be **no**. But please do have an array of *all* objects on the scene. The width, height and coordinates of the object should be stored in variables in the object. Leaking these things would quickly become a burden; rendering the code complex and introduce bugs (*please see [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)*).

Do note that I just said "array of all objects **on the scene**" =) There is a subtle but most important point in this quote:

Whenever you walk through objects to determine their position and whether they have collided with someone or not. Also have a look at your viewport boundaries and determine whether the object are still "on the scene" or not. For instance, if you have a space craft simulator of some kind and a star just passed the player's viewport from one side to the other and then of the screen, and there is no way for the star to return and become visible again, then there is no reason for the star to be left behind in the system any more. He should be deleted and removed. He should definitely not be stored in an array and become part of a future collision detection with the player's avatar! Such things could dramatically slow down your game.

### Bonus: Collision quick tips

1. Divide the screen into parts. There is no reason for you to look for a collision between two objects if one of them are on left side of the screen, and the other one is on the right side. You could split up the screen into more logical units than just left and right too.
2. Always strive to have a cheap computation made first. We kind of already did that in the last tip. But even if you now know that two objects just might be in collision with each other, draw two logical squares around your objects. For instance, say you have two 2D airplanes, then there is no reason for you to first look if some part of their wings collide. Draw a square around each airplane, effectively capturing their largest width and their largest height. If these two squares do not overlap, then just like in the last tip, you know they cannot be in collision with each other. But, if your first-phase cheap computation hinted that they might be in collision, pass those two airplanes to another more expensive computation to really look into the matter a bit more.

Comment: Your answer is pretty much how I invisioned it to be honest. It's good to have it backed up in such a complete manner. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score -2):

I am still working on something i wanted to make lots of divs and make them act on physics. I will share somethings that weren't obvious to me at first.

1. Detect collisions in data first. I was reading the x and y of boxes on screen then checking against other divs. After a week it occurred to me how stupid this was. I mean first i would assign a new value to div, then read it from div. Accessing divs is expensive. Think dom as a rendering stage.
2. Use webworkers if possible easy.
3. Use canvas if possible.
4. And if possible make elements carry a list of elements they should be checked against for collision.(this would be helpful in only certain cases).

I learned that interactive collisions are way more expensive. Because you have to check for changes in environment while in normal interaction you simulate what is going to happen in future, and therefore your animation would be more fluid and more cpu available.

i made something very very early stage just for fun: http://www.lastnoob.com/

Comment: Muhammad, I am so sorry for casting a downvote on your answer. I really am. But I had no choice. Most of all you wrote, had nothing to do with the question. CaptainCarl has already chosen the Canvas API. He is not dealing with divs on a page. And I must say that your list item #4, that is the one that could be related to the question, is a bad design. Bad not only for games but for all types of applications. You're leaking information across domains, it's like asking for trouble. Sadly though, I cannot elaborate and explain the life cycle of game logic in a comment. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: hmm ok. could you explain how #4 is a bad idea.

Comment: Please have a read about [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). Know that coupling is **sometimes** a desirable thing. Compare the datastructure of a linked list. Each element should have a pointer to the next element. Only the last element (tail) must have a null pointer. In your example, we are talking about DOM elements. "Clearly" if I may say so myself, they should not know a thing about who else "they should" be collision-checked against. Such is fully part of the game logic.

Comment: I forgot to add this would only work of non interactive simulated animations. Like rain. Where user can't act. Lets 2 boxes are going in opposite direction with same speed, both shouldn't have to worry about collision with the each other in noninteractive environment.  But if it was dynamic, so if user hits the box that and it starts to go in direction of other box with greater speed than eventually there could be collision so they need to check for it. As environment may change anytime they need to check continuously. Also dom elements wont know anything but js representation would.

Comment: What drives the simulation is actually **nobodies** concern. For now it is automated, but in a week's time it might just as well be one thousand users in a distributed game. Your logical computation engine, or JavaScript module, has the sole responsibility to know and care about which divs are colliding with which other divs.

To continue your rain drops example: The rain drops themselves does not know one bit about their outside world. They shouldn't even know about gravity. On the other hand, they should know their weight. The weight in turn is used by a "Planet" to calculate their gravity.

Comment: but js would know which raindrop has possibility of colliding, and then can assign a list to check against them. Thus save time. But as said before world that's interactive can't use this. This technique is useless and actually breaks the collision detection there. Cause everything would be unexpected. List would be a lie. In simulation, the list system does have its use. Does it make sense to check for a collision with something that is going and only going to go in opposite direction in all xyz. Or with stuff that is 100 miles away.

Comment: Muhammad, there are more things about your script that I do not understand than what I do understand. **You** are the sole master, the expert, of your script and all of its use cases. So do whatever you feel is the best solution and design. There can never be new knowledge added to the humankind unless we have entrepreneurs that dare walk on roads no one else walked on before! I wish you the best.